# How to invoke a method of child class dynamically which specified by string value in base class?

Tags: java, android

Here is tried code.

```
public class ChildB extends BaseA {
    public void showMessage() {
        Log.d("myTest", "Here is ChildB.");
    }
}


public class ChildC extends BaseA {
    public void showMessage() {
        Log.d("myTest", "Here is ChildC.");
    }
}


public class NormalD {
    public void showMessage() {
        Log.d("myTest", "Here is NormalD.");
    }
}


public class BaseA {
    public void showMessage(String sSpecifiedChild) {
        sSpecifiedChild.showMessage();  <== I'd like to invoke a child method specified by String value.
    }
}


public class MainActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_jelly_notification);

        BaseA baseA = new BaseA();

        baseA.showMessage("ChildC");
        baseA.showMessage("ChildB");
        baseA.showMessage("NormalD");   <== occurs an exception because "NormalD" is not child of BaseA.
    }
}
```

Desired result is : 
Here is ChildC. 
Here is ChildB.

It occurs an exception of NormalD.

Comment: Have a look at Reflection

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thanks. Your answer helped for me. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the object using some class or @class property parameter in base class. Prepare the object using that property and for any derived class you can use the same function and it will going to call. You can [have a look at it](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind)

Comment: Thanks for answer.  I solved the problem through @ScaryWombat's.